# NodeJS and yarn are missing from $PATH

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, users

On my machine, I have NodeJS and Yarn installed. If I open a new command line window I can successfully use their respective `node` and `yarn` commands. If I use `which` on them, I get `/usr/bin/node` and `/usr/bin/yarn` respectively.

The problem I am running into is when I take the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd <directory with yarn package info>
yarn install
```

and run it through NodeJS' child process API, I get an error saying `yarn: command not found`

While attempting to figure out what is wrong, I first checked the path from the script and `/usr/bin` was included. I then added a which for the two commands along with python3 in the shell script. The two I need showed nothing while python3 showed `/usr/bin/python3`. I then ran `ls -l /usr/bin` from the script and there are a substantial number of missing links and commands compared to when I ran it from a normal shell.

What could be causing this? I've exhausted the extend of my Linux knowledge and the only thing that comes to mind is a user / group or permission related issue.

EDIT:
Output of $PATH is

```
/snap/<app_name>/x1/usr/sbin:
/snap/<app_name>/x1/usr/bin:
/snap/<app_name>/x1/sbin:
/snap/<app_name>/x1/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:
/snap/<app_name>/x1/gnome-platform/usr/bin
```

Output of `ls -l /usr/bin`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      51384 Jan 18  2018 [
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22696 Sep 27  2018 aa-enabled
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22696 Sep 27  2018 aa-exec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22608 Mar  5 11:23 addpart
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35032 Jan 18  2018 arch
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          4 Jul  7 05:47 awk -> mawk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      55512 Jan 18  2018 b2sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39096 Jan 18  2018 base32
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39096 Jan 18  2018 base64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 basename
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       7115 Jun  6  2019 bashbug
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      34952 May  3 06:30 bootctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      67672 May  3 06:30 busctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          3 May 23  2018 captoinfo -> tic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       3329 Jun  4 12:25 catchsegv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        853 Jul 15  2016 cautious-launcher
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root shadow    71816 Mar 22  2019 chage
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         11 Jun 18  2017 chardet3 -> chardetect3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        389 Jun 18  2017 chardetect3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14336 Jan 22 08:40 chattr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      63672 Jan 18  2018 chcon
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      76496 Mar 22  2019 chfn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30800 Mar  5 11:23 chrt
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      44528 Mar 22  2019 chsh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 cksum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10240 May 23  2018 clear
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10312 Jun  6  2019 clear_console
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        390 Jan 15 10:35 cloud-id
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        394 Jan 15 10:35 cloud-init
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       2108 Jan 14 14:27 cloud-init-per
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47200 Aug  4  2017 cmp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39128 Jan 18  2018 comm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         11 Jul 15  2016 compose -> run-mailcap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         35 Aug  7  2018 console-conf -> ../share/subiquity/console-conf-tui
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       1565 Jul  7 05:45 core-sshd-host-keygen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       6332 May 27 14:15 c_rehash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      51416 Jan 18  2018 csplit
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          6 May 11 09:40 ctstat -> lnstat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43224 Jan 18  2018 cut
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10224 Jun 11 13:25 dbus-cleanup-sockets
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     236584 Jun 11 13:25 dbus-daemon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22520 Jun 11 13:25 dbus-monitor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10224 Jun 11 13:25 dbus-run-session
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26608 Jun 11 13:25 dbus-send
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14320 Jun 11 13:25 dbus-update-activation-environment
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10224 Jun 11 13:25 dbus-uuidgen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      20142 Oct 25  2017 deb-systemd-helper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       4434 Oct 25  2017 deb-systemd-invoke
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22608 Mar  5 11:23 delpart
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       2550 Apr  1  2018 dh_bash-completion
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     145752 Aug  4  2017 diff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      63704 Aug  4  2017 diff3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47296 Jan 18  2018 dircolors
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 dirname
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     153952 Sep  5  2019 dpkg-deb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     100568 Jan 18  2018 du
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       7297 Apr 13  2018 ec2metadata
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         11 Jul 15  2016 edit -> run-mailcap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          8 Jul  7 05:47 editor -> vim.tiny
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 env
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          8 Jul  7 05:47 ex -> vim.tiny
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39128 Jan 18  2018 expand
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root shadow    22808 Mar 22  2019 expiry
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47288 Jan 18  2018 expr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      75992 Jan 18  2018 factor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18728 Mar 22  2019 faillog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26704 Mar  5 11:23 fallocate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     238080 Nov  5  2017 find
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30880 Mar  5 11:23 flock
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43192 Jan 18  2018 fmt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 fold
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18512 Aug  9  2019 free
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30856 Jun  4 12:25 getconf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      31224 Jun  4 12:25 getent
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14408 Mar  5 11:23 getopt
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      75824 Mar 22  2019 gpasswd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     437264 Jan 10  2019 gpgv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 groups
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      21883 Apr 13  2018 growpart
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43224 Jan 18  2018 head
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       2514 Feb  2  2018 helpztags
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 hostid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18504 May  3 06:30 hostnamectl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          7 Mar  5 11:23 i386 -> setarch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      63744 Jun  4 12:25 iconv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43224 Jan 18  2018 id
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      59464 May 23  2018 infocmp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          3 May 23  2018 infotocap -> tic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     145664 Jan 18  2018 install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26704 Mar  5 11:23 ionice
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26768 Mar  5 11:23 ipcmk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26704 Mar  5 11:23 ipcrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      51280 Mar  5 11:23 ipcs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         19 Nov 11  2017 iptables-xml -> /sbin/xtables-multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10280 Dec 30  2017 ischroot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47320 Jan 18  2018 join
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         16 Jul  7 05:47 jsondiff -> python3-jsondiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         17 Jul  7 05:47 jsonpatch -> python3-jsonpatch
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         19 Jul  7 05:47 jsonpointer -> python3-jsonpointer
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         18 Jul  7 05:47 jsonschema -> python3-jsonschema
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       4508 Jan 28  2018 kernel-install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43088 Mar  5 11:23 last
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          4 Mar  5 11:23 lastb -> last
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18504 Mar 22  2019 lastlog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       7786 Feb 25  2018 lcf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       5422 Jun  4 12:25 ldd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          9 Jul  7 05:46 less -> /bin/less
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         13 Jul  7 05:46 lessecho -> /bin/lessecho
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         13 Jul  7 05:46 lessfile -> /bin/lessfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         12 Jul  7 05:46 lesskey -> /bin/lesskey
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         13 Jul  7 05:46 lesspipe -> /bin/lesspipe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 link
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          7 Mar  5 11:23 linux32 -> setarch
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          7 Mar  5 11:23 linux64 -> setarch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22888 May 11 09:40 lnstat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      50592 Jun  4 12:25 locale
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10240 Jan 30 06:28 locale-check
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22600 May  3 06:30 localectl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     338744 Jun  4 12:25 localedef
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47792 Mar  5 11:23 logger
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 logname
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10240 Jan 22 08:40 lsattr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      71760 Mar  5 11:23 lscpu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      71760 Mar  5 11:23 lsipc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35232 Mar  5 11:23 lslocks
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      63568 Mar  5 11:23 lslogins
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43088 Mar  5 11:23 lsmem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      38992 Mar  5 11:23 lsns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     125416 Apr  3  2018 mawk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30864 Mar  5 11:23 mcookie
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43224 Jan 18  2018 md5sum
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          6 Jan 18  2018 md5sum.textutils -> md5sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10312 Mar  5 11:23 mesg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35098 Apr  9  2018 miniterm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      63672 Jan 18  2018 mkfifo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     189432 Jul  5  2018 mksquashfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        865 Jul  7 05:45 mkswapfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26704 Mar  5 11:23 namei
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          4 Jul  7 05:47 nawk -> mawk
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      40344 Mar 22  2019 newgrp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 nice
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43288 Jan 18  2018 nl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 nohup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 nproc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      31008 Mar  5 11:23 nsenter
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26696 May 11 09:40 nstat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      63736 Jan 18  2018 numfmt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      67800 Jan 18  2018 od
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     723944 May 27 14:15 openssl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         14 Jul  7 05:47 pager -> ../../bin/less
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      88144 Mar  5 11:23 partx
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root      59640 Mar 22  2019 passwd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35032 Jan 18  2018 paste
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 pathchk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          6 Oct 25  2018 pdb3 -> pdb3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         23 Apr 17 20:56 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    2097720 Nov 19  2018 perl
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    2097720 Nov 19  2018 perl5.26.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26712 Aug  9  2019 pgrep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39128 Jan 18  2018 pinky
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Aug  9  2019 pkill -> pgrep
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18656 Jun  4 12:25 pldd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30808 Aug  9  2019 pmap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      71960 Jan 18  2018 pr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         11 Jul 15  2016 print -> run-mailcap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 printenv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      51384 Jan 18  2018 printf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35424 Mar  5 11:23 prlimit
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         28 Oct 15  2018 probert -> ../share/probert/bin/probert
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      71928 Jan 18  2018 ptx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10312 Aug  9  2019 pwdx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       7812 Oct 25  2018 py3clean
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      12119 Oct 25  2018 py3compile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         31 Oct 25  2018 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          8 Oct 25  2018 pydoc3 -> pydoc3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         79 Apr 17 20:56 pydoc3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         12 Oct 25  2018 pygettext3 -> pygettext3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      21547 Apr 17 20:56 pygettext3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        372 Sep 25  2017 pyjwt3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          9 Oct 25  2018 python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4526456 Apr 17 20:56 python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4526456 Apr 17 20:56 python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       1018 Oct 28  2017 python3-jsondiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       3661 Oct 28  2017 python3-jsonpatch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       1342 May  1  2016 python3-jsonpointer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        398 Nov 15  2017 python3-jsonschema
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         10 Oct 25  2018 python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          3 Jul  7 05:47 rcp -> scp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26696 May 11 09:40 rdma
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47320 Jan 18  2018 realpath
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14408 Mar  5 11:23 rename.ul
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14408 Mar  5 11:23 renice
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          4 May 23  2018 reset -> tset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      38992 Mar  5 11:23 resizepart
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10312 Mar  5 11:23 rev
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         30 Jul 11  2017 rgrep
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          3 Jul  7 05:47 rlogin -> ssh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        208 May 11 09:40 routef
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       1656 May 11 09:40 routel
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          3 Jul  7 05:47 rsh -> ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          6 May 11 09:40 rtstat -> lnstat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 runcon
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18161 Jul 15  2016 run-mailcap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          8 Jul  7 05:47 rview -> vim.tiny
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10469 Dec 30  2017 savelog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     100496 Mar  4  2019 scp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30792 Mar  5 11:23 script
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26704 Mar  5 11:23 scriptreplay
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      51296 Aug  4  2017 sdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         11 Jul 15  2016 see -> run-mailcap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       2442 Mar 12  2018 select-editor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       1209 Mar 12  2018 sensible-browser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       1109 Mar 12  2018 sensible-editor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        433 Mar 12  2018 sensible-pager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47288 Jan 18  2018 seq
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18784 Mar  5 11:23 setarch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10312 Mar  5 11:23 setsid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43088 Mar  5 11:23 setterm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     153960 Mar  4  2019 sftp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          6 Mar 22  2019 sg -> newgrp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47320 Jan 18  2018 sha1sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      55512 Jan 18  2018 sha224sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      55512 Jan 18  2018 sha256sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      59608 Jan 18  2018 sha384sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      59608 Jan 18  2018 sha512sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      59608 Jan 18  2018 shred
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      55480 Jan 18  2018 shuf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      26704 Aug  9  2019 skill
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18512 Aug  9  2019 slabtop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          3 Mar  4  2019 slogin -> ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         32 Jul  7 05:47 snap -> /snap/snapd/current/usr/bin/snap
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         20 Jul  7 05:47 snapctl -> ../lib/snapd/snapctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          5 Aug  9  2019 snice -> skill
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     113120 Jan 18  2018 sort
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      55936 Jan 18  2018 split
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     727848 Mar  4  2019 ssh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     346248 Mar  4  2019 ssh-add
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab  362640 Mar  4  2019 ssh-agent
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       1456 Jan 16  2018 ssh-argv0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10658 Oct  2  2017 ssh-copy-id
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     420000 Mar  4  2019 ssh-keygen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     420000 Mar  4  2019 ssh-keyscan
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      80088 Jan 18  2018 stat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47288 Jan 18  2018 stdbuf
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root     149080 Jan 31 11:18 sudo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          4 Jan 31 11:18 sudoedit -> sudo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      56128 Jan 31 11:18 sudoreplay
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39104 Jan 18  2018 sum
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1558792 May  3 06:30 systemd-analyze
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10312 May  3 06:30 systemd-cat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14408 May  3 06:30 systemd-cgls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30816 May  3 06:30 systemd-cgtop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22600 May  3 06:30 systemd-delta
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10304 May  3 06:30 systemd-detect-virt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43104 May  3 06:30 systemd-mount
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10304 May  3 06:30 systemd-path
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      88136 May  3 06:30 systemd-resolve
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43080 May  3 06:30 systemd-run
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18504 May  3 06:30 systemd-socket-activate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14408 May  3 06:30 systemd-stdio-bridge
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         13 May  3 06:30 systemd-umount -> systemd-mount
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14328 May 23  2018 tabs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39096 Jan 18  2018 tac
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      67832 Jan 18  2018 tail
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30800 Mar  5 11:23 taskset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35032 Jan 18  2018 tee
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47288 Jan 18  2018 test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      84080 May 23  2018 tic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        815 Jul  7 05:47 timedatectl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22600 May  3 06:30 timedatectl.real
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39552 Jan 18  2018 timeout
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14424 Aug  9  2019 tload
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      14328 May 23  2018 toe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     108304 Aug  9  2019 top
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         10 Jul  6 23:54 touch -> /bin/touch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18456 May 23  2018 tput
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47288 Jan 18  2018 tr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39096 Jan 18  2018 truncate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22528 May 23  2018 tset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 tsort
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 tty
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      15397 Jun  4 12:25 tzselect
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      40685 Feb 25  2018 ucf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      19367 Feb 25  2018 ucfq
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10722 Feb 25  2018 ucfr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      39128 Jan 18  2018 unexpand
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43224 Jan 18  2018 uniq
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 unlink
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18712 Mar  5 11:23 unshare
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      98008 Jul  5  2018 unsquashfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      47112 Sep  5  2019 update-alternatives
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      10312 Aug  9  2019 uptime
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      35000 Jan 18  2018 users
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22600 Mar  5 11:23 utmpdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       6913 Apr 13  2018 vcs-run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          8 Jul  7 05:47 vi -> vim.tiny
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          8 Jul  7 05:47 view -> vim.tiny
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1108024 Mar 18 13:29 vim.tiny
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      34912 Aug  9  2019 vmstat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          8 Jul  7 05:47 w -> w.procps
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty       30800 Mar  5 11:23 wall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      22952 Aug  9  2019 watch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      43200 Jan 18  2018 wc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      27144 Mar  5 11:23 whereis
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         10 Jul  6 23:54 which -> /bin/which
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      51416 Jan 18  2018 who
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 whoami
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      63488 Sep 17  2019 wpa_passphrase
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18504 Aug  9  2019 w.procps
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          7 Mar  5 11:23 x86_64 -> setarch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      71896 Nov  5  2017 xargs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         38 Jul  7 05:47 xdg-open
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        886 Jul  7 05:47 xdg-settings
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18552 Mar 18 13:29 xxd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      30904 Jan 18  2018 yes
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      18488 Jun  4 12:25 zdump
```

Snippet of the output from a regular command line window (which are all missing when ran from the shell script):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          22 Mar  9 10:51 yarn -> ../share/yarn/bin/yarn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          22 Mar  9 10:51 yarnpkg -> ../share/yarn/bin/yarn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       63720 Apr  7 15:15 yelp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       39256 Sep  5  2019 yes
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         409 Apr 10 08:47 youtube-dl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Apr 29 12:37 ypdomainname -> hostname
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1258822/edit) how us the complete output of `ls -l /usr/bin/node` and the complete output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: @user535733 Ok, I added the additional information

Comment: Look at your output: There is no 'node' (nor 'yarn') file or link in /usr/bin/. I don't know where you installed them to, but it's not /usr/bin.

Comment: "I then ran ls -l /usr/bin from the script and there are a substantial number of missing links and commands compared to when I ran it from a normal shell". I know that's the case but why is that happening?

Comment: I added a snippet of the output from `ls -l /usr/bin` when ran from a normal command line window.

Comment: Is your question really "Why does NodeJS' child process API ignore many commands in /usr/bin?" If you are running commands through some node script, then I don't quite see how $PATH is the issue.

Comment: Because if PATH was working properly, yarn and node should be able to be identified when I called from the script. But since it's not, something is clearly wrong with the PATH and it's contents

Comment: From your description so far as I can determine: When you don't use node, you get correct output.  When you do use node you get incorrect output. Recall that $PATH is merely an evironment variable. It's not an application.

Comment: And I'm aware of that. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is some strange user or permission related issue that could arise and cause a majority of the links on the path to be missing. I've already read through the docs and asked on NodeJS related resources and I'm getting a sense this is OS related, not NodeJS (I'm able to access yarn when I run bat scripts on Window so I know the approach works)

Comment: According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) "The command lookup will be performed using options.env.PATH environment variable if passed in options object, otherwise process.env.PATH will be used." So, what's the output of `console.log(process.env.PATH)` in a nodejs script?

Comment: The same as what is printed from the script